# Best way in REST api to request a summary representation of a resource?

Tags: rest

I have a REST api that deals with a large resource, customers. The client sometimes wants an abbreviated/summary representation of a customer.  What would be a good way to specify that the request is for a summary representation?

To get a full representation for customer 123 its: `/customers/123`

To get a summary representation is `/customers/123/summary` a good way?
Are there better options?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make your solution reusable and flexible, I would suggest implementing a "filter" query parameter. In there, you can put any fields required by the client:

```
GET /customers/123?fields=id,first_name,last_name,email
```

That way if later you need to create a different summary for a different task, you won't have anything to modify.

I wouldn't recommend `/customers/123/summary` because it's not flexible. It might be ok for one case, but if the client needs to access different properties for a different case, you will have to tweak the resource (most likely by returning more fields than needed). If you want to "hide" the field names, perhaps an alternative could be something like this:

```
GET /customers/123?view=DESCRIPTION
```

Where "`DESCRIPTION`" would describe the type of summary. For example:

```
GET /customers/123?view=addresses_only // eg. returns billing and home address
GET /customers/123?view=short // eg. returns only id, first name, last name
```

This is still flexible since you can easily create new views.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and I can see how it is flexible.  One concern I have with this approach, is that it assumes the consumer knows the available fields for the customer resource.

Comment: In both cases, whether it's /summary or /?field=..., you will still need to share a URL with the client. They don't need to know the available fields if you simply give them the URL yourself. I've updated my post with another possible solution.

Comment: just consider the increased flexibility of `?fields=...` is not free. you're expanding the surface or your API, now you need to validate (whitelist) the fields you expose, you're giving more control to the client, and that has pros and cons.

Comment: I like the idea but I find little difference between the `GET /customers/123?view=short` and `/GET /customers/123/short`. Both mean the getting the short version of the data and the fields to be returned could change in either approach. I am trying to find a selling point for the `view` approach.

Comment: I can see one advantage being that you don't have to modify your API with the view= approach. If you start with /short and decide you need /addressed_only and then /full_names you're going to keep modifying your api and it's going to get large if you have multiple endpoints that do this.